# JOIN table on results of other JOINs with supertype table

Tags: mysql, sql

```
t1
-id (pk 1-to-1 references s.id)
-t2_id (fk)
-data

t2
-id (pk 1-to-1 references s.id)
-t3_id (fk)
-data

t3
-id (pk 1-to-1 references s.id)
-data

s
-id (pk)
-data

jt
-s_id (pk references s.id)
-ot_id (pk references ot.id)

ot
-id (pk)
-data
```

The application ensures that `t1`, `t2`, and `t3` do not have the same value for an `id`.

I can easily INNER JOIN `t1`, `t2`, and `t3` using foreign keys `t2_id` and `t3_id` resulting in a collection of their IDs which all also belong to supertype table `s` using a one-to-one relationship.

How can I JOIN junction table `jt` to the above results and in turn JOIN other table `ot` to that result?

My end result is a collection of ot.data where `t1.id=123`.

I am thinking of the the following, but it just seems a little weird.

```
SELECT ot.data
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON t2.id=t1.t2_id
INNER JOIN t3 ON t3.id=t2.t3_id
INNER JOIN jt ON jt.s_id=t1.id OR jt.s_id=t2.id OR jt.s_id=t3.id
INNER JOIN ot ON ot.id=jt.ot_id
WHERE t1.id=123;
```

Or maybe the following, or maybe a correlated query?

```
SELECT ot.data
FROM ot
INNER JOIN jt ON jt.ot_id=ot.id
WHERE ot.id IN (
  SELECT COALESCE(s1.id,s2.id,s3.id)
  FROM t1
  INNER JOIN t2 ON t2.id=t1.t2_id
  INNER JOIN t3 ON t3.id=t2.t3_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN s s1 ON s1.id=t1.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN s s2 ON s2.id=t2.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN s s3 ON s3.id=t3.id
  WHERE t1.id=123
);
```

Or maybe?

```
SELECT ot.data
FROM ot
INNER JOIN jt ON jt.ot_id=ot.id
WHERE ot.id IN (
  SELECT t2_id id FROM t1 WHERE t1.id=123
  UNION SELECT t3_id id FROM t2 INNER JOIN t1 ON t1.t2_id=t2.id WHERE t1.id=123
)
OR ot.id=123;
```

Comment: aaaaand the code, you tried, the research you done, or the money you wana pay to do your job just lost while your post travelled through the internet...

Answer (score 0):

OK, you have three sets of IDs and you want the corresponding data for each ID.

Here we have the list of possible data what we can get back:

```
SELECT
  s.id AS S_id, s.data AS S_data,
  ot.id AS OT_id, ot.data AS OT_DATA
FROM
  s
  INNER JOIN jt
    ON s.id = jt.s_id
  INNER JOIN ot
    ON jt.ot_id = ot.id
```

Now, if we don't need anything from the three tables you have, it means, we  are searching for all the records in the result of the query above where the `s.id` is included in one of the tables. Semantically, this means 3 where conditions, both three states, that the id is included in one of the tables:

```
SELECT
  s.id AS S_id, s.data AS S_data,
  ot.id AS OT_id, ot.data AS OT_DATA
FROM
  s
  INNER JOIN jt
    ON s.id = jt.s_id
  INNER JOIN ot
    ON jt.ot_id = ot.id
WHERE
  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE t1.id = s.id)
  OR EXISTS (SELECT * FROM t2 WHERE t2.id = s.id)
  OR EXISTS (SELECT * FROM t3 WHERE t3.id = s.id)
```

If you need the data from the t1..t3 tables, just union them and join the leftovers to the union's result (as sagi mentioned it in (s)he's answer).

**Note**
Test if the following solution is faster or not.. I am not sure if the MySQL optimizer can or can not find the shortcut in OR-ed predicates.

```
SELECT
  s.id AS S_id, s.data AS S_data,
  ot.id AS OT_id, ot.data AS OT_DATA
FROM
  s
  INNER JOIN jt
    ON s.id = jt.s_id
  INNER JOIN ot
    ON jt.ot_id = ot.id
WHERE
  EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM t1 WHERE t1.id = s.id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 FROM t2 WHERE t2.id = s.id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 FROM t3 WHERE t3.id = s.id
  )
```

@TODO: run an explain and some test with both queries and use the one which seems to be better in performance.

Comment: The last one is basically the same as mine, and should produce the same performance (exists is just like a join)

Comment: Actually not, EXISTS not the same as INNER JOIN. Exists will return as soon as it finds a matching record and stops accessing the table while join will access all the tables and records to find all connected records. (however, the end result of the actual execution plan depends on the RDBMS and it's optimizer, this is why I said to test if it differs or not from other options)

Comment: Get the explain plan out, and you will see that probably exists does full scan as well. I didn't meant they work the same, i meant the usually have the same performance. BTW, exists won't always perform better then a join!

Comment: Anyways, I don't understand why but the OP doesn't want UNION, he think it will affect his results somehow and that it will hurt performance.

Comment: Because it is counter intuitive in some cases. To be more specific, it seems to be a bad idea since unions are mostly represented as subqueries and users with less experience tends to think, that subqueries are always causing performance problems.